# Facebook dont pick up the image on the page when sharing my website

Tags: html, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

When i post my page on facebook, or someone else share it.

it's not picking up the image i have in the page, even that the tag og:img exist.

Can someone figure out what's going on ?

Url for example :

https://www.localtells.com/hotel/Sir_Albert_Hotel_Amsterdam_420896/

Thanks !

Comment: Debug the url you're trying to share on facebook and see if you're missing any tags. If the given url is indeed yours, you're missing an 'og:url' tag.

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.localtells.com%2Fhotel%2FSir_Albert_Hotel_Amsterdam_420896%2F . You have a bunch of crap before you head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to run the URL through the Facebook debugger to work out what's wrong which is here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.localtells.com%2Fhotel%2FSir_Albert_Hotel_Amsterdam_420896

On the initial call to the page it didnt load the image. However on the second call it will get the image. This is something to do with how Facebook scraps the  page and it's really frustrating .

To get around the issue you need to pass the resolution of the image in 2 more tags, then it renders on the first share

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

The reference for these tags is here http://ogp.me/#array

Good luck with your page!